# Clojureのライブラリとtools.reader

Tags: clojure

Clojure1.6と1.7のバージョン間互換についてです。

以下project.cljで依存ライブラリを指定しています。

```clj
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-beta2"]
                 [compojure "1.3.2"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.16"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.3.2"]　;; <1>
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.4"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3211"] ;; <2>
                 [cljs-http "0.1.30"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.8.8"]]
```

現状clojureにはstableなver.1.6とbetaの1.7がありますが、どうやらこの２つは内部のtools.readerに互換性がないようです。上の場合だと1.7依存のclojurescript<1>は動きますが、1.6依存のringサーバー<2>では「read関数に渡す引数の数が違う」という趣旨のエラーが出ます。
　そこで、1.7のreaderを使うclojurescript<1>と1.6以前のライブラリ<2>において、それぞれ内部で使うtools.readerのバージョンを陽に指定する方法はないでしょうか。
　もしくはもっと根本的に、1.6 - 1.7間のreader互換性の問題を解決できる方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、tools.readerはClojureの標準ライブラリではなく、独立したcontribライブラリなので、Clojureのバージョンが1.6なのか1.7なのかというのはここでは関係ありません。
ring-core 1.3.2が依存しているtools.readerのバージョン(0.8.1)とClojureScript 0.0-3211が依存しているバージョン(0.9.1)に互換性がないことが問題のようです。具体的にはエラーメッセージを見てみないと分からないですが、0.9.0で`read-string`のアリティが新たに追加されているのでこれが原因と思われます。

対症療法としては以下の3つが考えられるでしょうか。

- ClojureScriptのバージョンを0.0-3178に下げる
- ring-coreのバージョンを1.4.0-beta1に上げる
- `[ring/ring-core "1.3.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.reader]]`する

1つめのClojureScriptのバージョンを下げる方法が一番無難だと思います。バージョンを0.0-3178まで下げると依存するtools.readerのバージョンが0.8.xになるのでread-stringのアリティの問題は解決されるはずです。ClojureScriptは現在、1週間に1回以上リビジョンが上がるようなペースで開発が進められています。特別な理由がなければ最新版を使う必要もないと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

2つめは逆にring-coreのバージョンを上げることで、tools.readerのバージョンをClojureScriptに揃える方法です。ただし、1.4.0はまだbeta1が出たばかりという段階なのであまりお薦めはできません。

3つめは、使用するring-coreおよびClojureScriptのバージョンはそのままに、ring-coreからtools.readerをexcludeする方法です。ring-core内でtool.readerを使っているのは`ring.middleware.session.cookie`だけのようなので、この名前空間を使わないのであれば問題なくexcludeできる可能性があります。

Comment: なるほど、clojure本体とは独立したライブラリなのですね、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。
　しかし、異なるライブラリで、「異なるバージョンの同一のライブラリ」を参照してしまい、また今回のようにそれに互換性がない場合、使用する側で調整するしかないのでしょうか？
　基本的にライブラリのバージョンは後方互換があることが前提で、今回がレアケースなのはわかるのですが。

Comment: そこはまぁ、ClojureやLeiningenの問題というよりはJVMの問題(いわゆる「JAR地獄」)かと思います。Javaの場合だと、クラスローダを駆使したworkaroundもありますが、Clojureの場合はクラスロードの管理だけでは十分でなく、同名の名前空間を別で持っておくような仕組みがないので素直に実現するのは難しいでしょうね。

Comment: クラスローダで検索してみたところ、かなり典型的な問題だったようですね。clojureやjavaの内部について少し勉強してみます。ありがとうございました。